# TCP session during bearer-addition/switch event in LTE

Tags: tcp, lte

I am working on LTE-EPC software application and get a theory-based problem.

1. There is a single UE and a single PDN.
2. There is a default-way-connection between them through P-GW/S-GW/eNB.
3. UE sends request for additional resource allocation and PCEF/PCRF approves it.
4. Now system establishes additional bearer for UE.

What will happen to the tcp session already set in the default bearer? Should it be reestablished? Or packets will be routed through the additional bearer? Is there any good informational resource about this situation?

Answer (score 1):

specification number correct :-).

I think as per the specification 3GPP TS 23.401 , the connection is UDP based and not TCP.
If any new service is requested by an UE ,the LTE network element will try to either serve using a dedicated or default bearer.
In response to your query, this is what would happen : The connection will not be re-established but instead an dedicated bearers would be established.

For more information on LTE stack,dedicated bearers ,Please refer : 3GPP TS 23.401 latest release

Answer (score 1):

Any new additional service request shall not cause re-establishment of the already existing bearer but it will be served in the form of establishment of additional dedicated bearer incase if it is not feasible to serve using the already existing default bearer.